# Estimating Normal Distribution Probability Using Simulation in R

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

**Question:** Use simulations in R to numerically estimate $P(X<Y)$ for $X \sim N(0,1)$, $Y \sim N(1,5)$ with X and Y independent.

My Solution:

```
simfunc <-function(sims,n){
  res <- rep(0, sims)
  for(i in 1:sims){
    X <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
    Y <- rnorm(n, 1, 5)
    count <-0
    for (j in 1:n){
      if(X[j] < Y[j])
        count=count+1
    }
    res[i] <-count/n
  }
  finalres <- mean(res)
  return(finalres)
}
```

So basically sims is the number of simulations we are running while n is the number of independent normal values we are generating. If X < Y, then count is incremented. Count/n gives the probability of X < Y for that simulation, and is stored in a result vector. Finally result vector mean is calculated.

Is my solution formulated correctly?

Comment: You edited your code a month after your question was answered. Now your code doesn't run at all. You also unaccepted my answer a month after accepting it. If you want any more help you need to explain what it is that you are still looking for because, as your brief question stands, it has been answered.

Comment: @Gordon Because the changes were minor and did not improve the question in any way, I have rolled it back to its preceding version.

Answer (score 8):

Your code will run and give a correct answer, but it is written in Fortran-like style.
As R code, it is spectacularly inefficient because you're not making use of R's vectorizations.

Your code is also overly long and convoluted for the stated aim.
If indeed you simply want to  estimate the probability by simulation, as your question states, then much simpler and faster code would be:

```
> n <- 1e6
> X <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
> Y <- rnorm(n, 1, 5)
> mean(X<Y)
[1] 0.578
```

Did you perhaps have some extra aims that you have failed to state? Was there some reason why you conducted multiple simulations and then combined them instead of generating all the random deviates at once?
Were you perhaps trying to estimate variability between simulation runs? Your code does not do that at present -- as your code stands, the multiple simulations (`1:nsims`) have no purpose but simply add to complexity.

Of course, you could compute the desired probability to full machine accuracy in R without using simulations by:

```
pnorm(1, sd=sqrt(26), lower.tail=FALSE).
```

I assume there is some pedagogic reason why you want to use a simulation.

PS. As it stands, your question is likely to get closed because it is a pure code question and therefore out of scope for CV.

Comment: Since $Y-X\sim\text{N}(1,sqrt(1+5^2))$, a one line answer is `mean(rnorm(1e6,1,sqrt(1+5*5))>0)`

Comment: @Xi'an Sure, but that seems out of the spirit of the question to me. If we're going to add analytic simplifications to the code, then we may as well just compute the exact probability using pnorm(1,sd=sqrt(26),lower.tail=FALSE). I've tried the answer the question as stated, which presumably had some sort of pedagogic motivation.